# Why does this count always return 1?

Tags: php, regex, function, count

I have the following function to count the amount of characters in the  tag. The output is always '1' even when I know for a fact it is more then a single digit. What am I doing wrong?

```
$www = $_POST['url'];
$url = file_get_contents($www);
```

[some more code]

```
function countTitle() {
global $url;
$search = "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/";

preg_match($search, $url, $result);

$title = $result[1]; // to string
$counttitle = count($title);
echo $counttitle;   
}
```

I know the regexp works because I use the following function to echo the title tag:

```
function getTitle() {
global $url;
$search = "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/";

preg_match($search, $url, $result);

$title = $result[1]; // to string
echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Are you sanitizing the value of `$www`?  What happens if `$_POST['url`]` is a URL or the path to a file on the server that you were not intending to be readable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`strlen( $str )`](http://php.net/strlen) to count the letters:

```
$myStr = 'Hello world';
echo strlen($myStr); // outputs 11
```

---

Strlen means **Str** ing **Len** gth.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `strlen()` instead of `count()`. I think `count()` casts to an array first, and then counts the number of elements in that array, which in this case is `1`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `strlen()` function, not `count()`.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using utf-8 encoding (non Latin characters) mb_strlen() will be more accurate.